# Details on the Microsoft multi-string format

Tags: c++, c, string, msdn

In [some of its API function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379793%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) Microsoft use the "multi-string" format to specify a list of strings.

As I understand it, a multi-string is a null-terminated buffer of concatenated null-terminated strings. But this can also be interpreted as a list of strings, separated by a null character and terminated by two null characters.

Here comes an example. A list composed of the following items:

```
"apple", "banana", "orange"
```

Becomes:

```
apple\0banana\0orange\0\0
```

But now I wonder:

How would an **empty list** be represented ?

Would it be:

```
\0
```

Or:

```
\0\0
```

I failed to found an accurate documentation that clarifies this. Any clue ?

Comment: The last string in a "string list" is the zero length string. A single \0 then is sufficient to terminate.

Comment: Wonder how this works with UTF-8 and its multibyte characters?

Comment: The Windows API doesn't support UTF-8 :-(  But if it did, nothing would change because UTF-8 multibyte characters never include \0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`\0`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx)

Comment: I bet this is your shortest answer ever ;) It perfectly answers my question though. Thank you.

Comment: I'm a man of few words.  If only you could say "It perfectly answers my question though. Thank you." just by clicking a checkmark...

Comment: So its not possible to have an empty string ("") in such a list?

Comment: No, it's not, just like you can't have `\0` inside a C string.

Answer (score 4):

It would be `\0`.

Raymond Chen [describes how this works on his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx):  the list of strings is terminated by an empty string.  If the first string in the list is empty, the list itself is empty.

Comment: Yes, that's a great article ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with these, many years ago, I wrote an STL style iterator which works on them:

http://noveltheory.com/iterators/Iterator_N3.htm